# How to get grid items to align center in Bootstrap views?

Tags: views, theming

I'm using Bootstrap views Drupal 7.

**Live site is over here to have a look at the code:**

http://xuzo.com/testing/

When a 3 column grid gets minimized, the 3 items stack 2 on top and 1 on the bottom.

But the bottom one is left aligned.

How can I have them align in the center so I get a nice triangle?

This looks easy with css, but I can't get it to work, tried:

```
 margin: 0 auto;
```

And others but can't get it working for some reason...

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can create div tag, you can use css as show below.

Example:

html: `<div class="secLayerContainer"><div class="secLayerContent">.....</div></div>`

css: 
.secLayerContainer { display: inline; float: left; width: 100% }
.secLayerContent { display: block; float: none; width: 200px; margin: 0px auto}

note: 200px also can change 20%. (your preference)

Comment: Not working....I'll just wait until the site is live and publish it, so someone can look at the live code.

Comment: @BrunoVincent Let me know if live. I will take a look.

Comment: I have put a link to the site here http://xuzo.com/testing/  @learnallskill

Comment: Add one more class at your last div. HTML: <div class=" col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4 imgCenter">  CSS: .imgCenter {
    display: block;
    float: none;
    margin: 0px auto;
}

Comment: How do I get into the HTML? What file? Approx line number? This is dynamic content yes?

Comment: Seem like you not really sure how to insert tag. I cant tell you because I never use this theme before. You can try this. HTML:nothing CSS: @media screen and (max-width: 1200px){.col-xs-12.col-sm-12.col-md-6.col-lg-4:nth-child(4) { display: block;  float: none; margin: 0px auto; } }